# Laravel query builder result to nested collection

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel, which is build with the Laravel query builder. I'm able to get the result, but now I want to put it in a nested collection. I want it in a nested collection, that I can use something like this in my view:

```
@foreach($lander AS $land)
    // do something with $land
    @foreach($land->companies as $company)
        // do something with $company
        @foreach($company->values as $value)
            // do something with $value
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This is my query result, which I want to put in the nested collection:

```
+-----------+---------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| 'land_id' | 'land'  |  'company_id' |  'company' |  'value_id' |  'value' |
+-----------+---------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
|         1 | Germany |             1 | Company1   |           1 | value1   |
|         1 | Germany |             1 | Company1   |           2 | value2   |
|         1 | Germany |             2 | Company2   |           3 | value3   |
|         1 | Germany |             2 | Company2   |           4 | value4   |
|         1 | Germany |             3 | Company3   |           5 | value5   |
|         2 | France  |             4 | Company4   |           7 | value6   |
|         2 | France  |             4 | Company4   |           8 | value7   |
|         2 | France  |             5 | Company5   |           9 | value8   |
+-----------+---------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

Edit:
currently I get the data with a DB::select() statement in a Repository and want to pass it as one object from the controller to the view.

**Edit2:** 
If this is not easy possible, the base of it all is this:
I have this DB situation with the defined relations (A,B,C,D,E are tables):

```
A -> hasMany(B)
B -> hasMany(C)
C -> belongsToMany(E) -> through Pivot Table (D)
```

Now I come from a object **E** and want a collection which I can use like this:

```
@foreach($A as $a)
    // do something with $a
    @foreach($a->B as $b)
        // do something with $b
        @foreach($b->C as $c)
            // do something with $c
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Edit3:** 
The answer from patricus is half working:

-> Hmm I took a look at the MySQL Query and this is strange...

**First**
It loads all A with the right conditions (E_id and a wherePivot)

**But then**
It loads all B where in (A_id)
It loads all C where in (B_id)
It loads all E where in (C_id)
--> But of course, this will result in a lot more records then the first wright query...

Comment: Are you using Eloquent to get the data back? Can you please share how you are getting the data and passing it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your Eloquent models and relationships setup correctly, you can do the following:

```
// question states you have E; code assumes E is $myE
$eId = $myE->id;

$myA = A::with('B.C.E')->whereHas('B.C.E', function($query) use ($eId) {
    $query->where('id', $eId);
});

// now you can loop through $myA, as you've described in your question.
```

The `with()` with eager load all the related objects, and the `whereHas` will make sure you're only getting the A records (and related objects) that are related to the E with the given id.

#### Edit

It took me a second, but I realize what your edit is saying, and what you mean by half working. You are correct that the eager loading will load more records than what is expected. To get this method to work, you would also need to add conditions to each step of the eager loading, but this gets really messy:

```
$eId = $myE->id;

$fn = function($q) use ($eId) {
    $q->where('id', $eId);
};

$myA = A::with([
        // restrict each eager load level individually
        'B' => function($q) use ($fn) {
            $q->whereHas('C.E', $fn);
        },
        'B.C' => function($q) use ($fn) {
            $q->whereHas('E', $fn);
        },
        'B.C.E' => $fn,
    ])
    // restrict the A query
    ->whereHas('B.C.E', $fn)
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Andi I have updated my answer, though it is a lot messier than I would like.

Comment: Hmm ok that looks like a working way... But isn't there a simpler way to establish this? (Probably a completly other way?)

Comment: It's not as clean as I hoped, but it works.. so thank you very much.

Comment: @Andi You can use closures (or defined functions) to clean it up a little. I've updated the code.